# If $f:(0,1)^n \rightarrow (0,1)$ is continuous, is $( x_1 ,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1 f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n),\ldots,x_n f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))$ an open map?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f:(0,1)^n \rightarrow (0,1)$, where $n>1$, is a continuous function. Define a function  $g : (0,1)^n \to (0,1)^n$ by 
$$g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n):=(x_1 f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n),\ldots,x_n f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))$$

from $(0,1)^n$ into $(0,1)^n$. Is it true that $g$ is an open map?

Intuitively, it seems $f$ must have more "degrees of freedom" to collapse an open set into a lower dimensional object. But I cannot formalize the intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping $f$ must have compact connected image, hence an interval $[a,b]\subset(0,1)$. Thus $g_i(x)=f(x)x_i\le b<1$, so that $g$ is not surjective. Thus it cannot be open: otherwise $g([0,1]^n)$ would be open and closed (it is compact), hence $g([0,1]^n)=[0,1]^n$ as the cube is connected.

The modified question in fact asks whether $g:(0,1)^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is open. Here, we can find a counterexample. Already in one variable consider $f(t)=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{1}{2}t^2$. This is just a parabola modified a bit to get $f([0,1])=[\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{2}]$ and the maximum at $t=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $g(t)=tf(t)$ is a cubic that maps $(0,1)$ onto $(0,\frac{1}{4}]$. The main point is that $g$ has local extreme at some interior point ($t=\frac{1}{2}$ in this case). For higher dimensions just take $(x_1f(x_1),\dots,x_nf(x_1))$.

On the other hand, back to $f:[0,1]^n\to (0,1)$ with image $[a,b]$, $a>0$. Let us show the image of $g$ has interior. We look at the cube $(0,1)^n$ as the union of open segments $I_p=(O,p)$ joining the origin $O$ and the points $p$ in its boundary; note that $\|p\|\ge1$. Now we  have $g(x)=f(x)\cdot x$, hence $g$ maps the segment $I_p$ into the line $L_p$ trough the origin and $p$, and the image must be connected, hence an interval. Since $f$ is continuous at $0$, we have $\lim_{x\to O}g(x)=0$, hence the image of $I_p$ is a segment $(0,q)$ or $(0,q]$ of the line $L_p$. In that segment we have the point $g(p/2)=f(p/2)(p/2)$, and
$$
\|g(p/2)\|=\tfrac{1}{2}f(p/2)\|p\|\ge \tfrac{1}{2}a.
$$ 
Thus, on every ray from the origin in the image of $g$ we have a segment of length
at least the fixed value $\frac{1}{2}a>0$. This gives non-empty interior.

Comment: I think your answer showed me I have to modify the question!

Comment: Thanks. My intuition was that for $n>1$, the result would be true. I should have been explicit. But I think I have a counterexample for that case as well.

Comment: Is that counterexample much different from a variation of the one variable one?

Comment: Your example made me recognize (again!) that I need something weaker. I only need that the image of $g$ has nonempty interior. I think I should spend more time thinking about the problem... Thanks for all your help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Again I only guess your settings, but if $f$ is given continuous on the _closed_ cube, then the image of $g$ has non-empty interior. I'll have to think what for arbitrary $f$ on the _open_ cube...

Comment: Yes, I can take $f$ to be continuous on the closed cube. I'm embarrassed but I'm still trying to figure out why this implies the image of $g$ has nonempty interior.

Comment: I've edited the quickly evolving post!

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question!